# Using chef to configure sftp access for AWS instances managed with OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, chef-infra

Hello all :) I'm new to ruby, chef, knife and OpsWorks (AWS' cloud deployment service).

I want to build a configuration where all the instances offer an sftp access to some part of their local file system; and I'm lost at how to do it with chef.

All I found is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/3954511), which is about an error setting up an sftp service.

Best regards

Edit: Please post if you know any other chef recipe that allows for access to the file system.

Comment: Do you know how to configure your systems without Chef (using bash, python or whatever you used before Chef)?

Answer (score 2):

We are using SFTP with chroots in AWS.

The solution is to:

1) use recipe: https://gist.github.com/werdan/5255517 - yes, I know it will be done as a community cookbook later on

Gist has comments that explain how to use this recipe

2) use SSH cookbook https://github.com/gchef/ssh-cookbook
3) use a role for nodes that goes like that (or set up attribute via wrapper cookbook):

```
name "has_sftp_users"
description "Server has chroot-ed user account to access files via SFTP"

run_list "recipe[ssh::chroot]"

override_attributes "ssh" => {"password_authentication" => "yes"}
```